# Content viewer Android

Tags: android, html, pdf, export, viewer

I'm trying to create an activity to show information about the monuments. What I thought is to create HTML files and then display them with a WebView. The problem is that I also need to export these contents on sdcard in some type of readable format (preferably pdf but I read some things and it seems very difficult and then I tried several solutions without success). How can I do this? Should I start from another type of format different from HTML?

Advise me a path to follow ... I do not know what else to try.

Thanks in advance. :)

Michele

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options. I would suggest go the PDF way.

If you have control over the contents, then the best way would be to create PDFs and you can then send a intent to open the PDF. If there are multiple PDF viewers available, then the intent will give an option for the user to select the viewer. If there is only one viewer available, the PDF will be opened in the viewer. If there are no available options, you can then send them to Google Play (Android Market) to download a PDF viewer and then view the PDF.